# Is memory per core more import than # of memory channels for high performance VASP calculation?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc

I am new in stackerflow

I ask this question cause recently my department want to purchase a HPC cluster mainly for first principle calculation. For now we have three choices:

(1) Per node dual CPU processor (AMD EPYC 7543, 32 cores per CPU, 8 memory channels per CPU), 16 * 32 GB DDR4 RAM. Total 16 computing nodes.

(2) Per node dual CPU processor (AMD EPYC 9334, 32 cores per CPU, 12 memory channels per CPU), 16 * 32 GB DDR5 RAM. Total 8 computing nodes.

(3) Per node dual CPU processor (AMD EPYC 9554, 64 cores per CPU, 12 memory channels per CPU), 24 * 16 GB DDR5 RAM. Tital 8 computing nodes.

I am very hesitant about choosing between three options. The CPU processor in option (1) is a little old, the memory channels are not fully utilized for dual CPU processors in option (2), and the memory per core is only 3 GB in option (3). Each option has its own disadvantages.

I am wondering which one would be better for running first-principles software such as VASP, CP2K, and QE. I hope someone could help me make a decision.

Comment: Memory can be a strong limitation, much more than performance. Indeed, if you cannot run your specific experiment or need swapping, then the cluster will be useless. Knowing the amount of RAM needed is hard. The best thing to do is to run this on an existing cluster an look the amount of RAM used. There is no reason for the amount of RAM used to drastically change from one machine to another (unless in some rare cases like the use of different devices like GPUs or very different algorithms).

Comment: Regarding performance, this is dependent of the operations actually run on the target cluster. A memory-bound application scaling well will run faster on (1). A compute-bound application scaling well will run faster on (1) and (3), and I expect (1) to be better in practice. If the application does not scale because of the interconnect, then (3) is the best. If it not scale on SMP systems, then (1) and (2) are better than (3). Again, the best thing to do is to profile the target applications in realistic conditions on an existing cluster so to then pick the best bast on the above infos.

Comment: The interconnect seems important here since VASP appears to [spent a significant time in expensive MPI collectives](https://www.hpcadvisorycouncil.com/pdf/200804%20VASP_Performance_and_Profiling.pdf) (all-to-all, all-reduce, bcast). Having more nodes with the same network link can help to increase the performance of some operations (dependant of the network topology). This parameter is pretty critical and should be considered with care : with a poor network and a communication-bound application, having more computing nodes can be useless (because the application will not scale).

Comment: Dear @JérômeRichard, very thanks to your detailed reply. I will choose one from (1) and (3). I will comment this question after my final decision.

Comment: Hi @JérômeRichard, I have one more option: (4) Per node dual CPU processor (AMD EPYC 7543, 32 cores per CPU, 8 memory channels per CPU), 24 * 16 GB DDR4 RAM. Total 16 computing nodes. The amount of RAM have exceeded largest number of memory channels of CPU. I want to know that will this have bad influence on the CPU performance?

Comment: (4) is (1) but only with less memory no? If so, it does not worth it.I find weird the fact that you get a "24" from power of two values (number of core, nodes, channels, and certainly the amount of RAM/channel).